# XSLT transformation to group items by time interval based on a timestamp

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a list of items that I want to group by time interval based on a timestamp information (in the example below startdate). For example, byc intervals of 3 seconds.

> For Example :

```
<ListItem>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:10.025+01:00</startdate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:11.025+01:00</startdate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:13.025+01:00</startdate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:14.025+01:00</startdate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:17.025+01:00</startdate>
    </item>
</ListItem>
```

> The expected result is:

```
<ItemmGroupe>
    <groupe>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:10.025+01:00</startdate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:11.023+01:00</startdate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>3</id>
            <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:13.020+01:00</startdate>
        </item>
    </groupe>
    <groupe>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
            <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:14.027+01:00</startdate>
        </item>
    </groupe>
    <groupe>
        <item>
            <id>5</id>
            <startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:17.025+01:00</startdate>
        </item>
    </groupe>
</ItemGroupe>
```

How can I do it using xslt transformation?

Comment: Which XSLT processor/tool do you use? Does it, like Saxon or Altova, also support XQuery where you can nicely express that with a `tumbling window` clause `for tumbling window $group in ListItem/item start $s when true() end next $n when xs:dateTime($n/startdate) - xs:dateTime($s/startdate) > xs:dayTimeDuration('PT3S')` https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhh? Or which version of XSLT, which processor do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0, you can use

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" 
             group-adjacent="my:timeSlot(xs:dateTime(startDate))">
      <groupe>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      ...
```

where `my:timeSlot` computes:

```
   xs:integer(($startDate - xs:dateTime('2000-01-01T00:00:00Z')) 
                 div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT3S'))
```